# Creating one sided border without changing size of <div> in bootstrap grid

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing a native DnD in html5 for a bootstrap 3 grid and i'm trying to generate indicators while dragging in between of two elements to tell the user he can drop the item at that spot.

Right now i'm adding `border-left` and `border-right` whenever the drag is hovering on the left or right side of the element. That basically works fine but when dragging over the borders to the next element the border jumps as the div size changes.

I've tried it with

- `outline` -> cannot create outline for only one side
- `box-shadow` -> cannot use styles like `dashed`

I made a simple fiddle that demonstrates the effect: https://jsfiddle.net/tmaqxh87/7/ (hover should simulate the DnD; the js is just for demonstration purpose)

Edit: my goal is to have one consistent line to appear between two boxes without any container changing the size. I would like to do that without generating any additional html elements.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: If you want the outer size of the div not to change when `border-width` changes, use `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: Unfortunately `box-sizing` doesn't work as my borders are added and deleted everytime the user drags over the containers

Comment: you could add a transparent border to all elements and then modify the colour of left on hover?

Comment: @RamRaider getting closer to what i want! Now the boxes don't move but the border is cut to half at the edges. I don't know if it's possible to cut it on top and bottom? Additional i would need to push the border out of the box so it would overlap with the other border, that would result into "looking like" one border.
I updated my fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tweaked the border so that there is always a border to the left and right - but transparent...

```css
.row>div {
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.col-xs-3{
    border-left:5px dashed transparent;
    border-right:5px dashed transparent;
    margin:0 -2.5px;
}

.col-xs-3:nth-of-type(odd):hover{
  border-right: 5px dashed black !important;
}
.col-xs-3:nth-of-type(even):hover{
  border-left: 5px dashed black !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="child" id="1">
      #
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="child" id="2">
      #
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="child" id="3">
      #
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="child" id="4">
      #
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost there, thank you alot ! :) now i just want the border to appear in the middle of the two elements. Like i need the border-right to be outside 2.5pxs on the right side and vise versa with the left one. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: modified the above, added `margin:0 -2.5px;`

Comment: glad it saved your day :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to give a solution with your question as per i Understood. I gave snippet below.please check and let me know is this what you want ? You can do it in css.

```css
.row>div {
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.col-xs-3:nth-of-type(odd):hover{
  border-right: 5px dashed black !important;
}
.col-xs-3:nth-of-type(even):hover{
  border-left: 5px dashed black !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="child" id="1">
      #
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="child" id="2">
      #
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="child" id="3">
      #
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="child" id="4">
      #
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a cool way to replace my JS in the fiddle but that JS was just demonstration purpose and unfortunately not the problem i was asking. I edited my question for clarification.