# How to add border line between two icons in bootstrap card?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add border line inside `card-header`. I have two icons - one on the left side and another on the right.

Here is an example:

[image]

**HMTL and CSS**:

```css
.card-header .compl {
  border-right: 2px solid;
  border-top-width: 12px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card bg-dark" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="compl float-start mp-5">
            <ion-icon name="checkmark" class="fs-4"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="views float-end">
            <ion-icon name="eye" class=" fs-4"></ion-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the.</p>
        <div class="progress" style="height: 8px;">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%;" aria-valuenow="50"
                aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe using a sided border would help. Take a look at [Creating one sided border without changing size of <div> in bootstrap grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688937/creating-one-sided-border-without-changing-size-of-div-in-bootstrap-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use your own icons remove fontawesome link this only for icons. above link and scripts attached in code is for bootstrap you are already using it so just ignore these.
Change border color from css

```css
.border-lr {
    border-right:2px solid black;
    border-left:3px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
 <!-- bootstrap 4 files you are already using  -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--for icon you can use your own -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  
<div class="container">
  <h2>Card Header and Footer</h2>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header border-0 p-0 bg-dark d-flex">
     <div class="py-3 px-4 border-lr"><i class="fas fa-file text-light"></i></div>
  <div class="ml-auto py-3 px-4"><i class="fas fa-bars text-light"></i></div>

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">Content</div> 
    <div class="card-footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```